# Need to check if struct has been initialized

Tags: c, struct, functional-programming, queue

Hi I am making a Queue abstact data type and I ran into a problem which I will try to explain as clearly as possible.
Basically I have a two structs one for an element and one for a queue (so you can initialize multiple queues).

```
struct element
{
    TYPE value;
    struct element* next;
};

struct queue
{
    struct element* head;
    struct element* tail;
    int element_counter;
};
```

And I have a function which initializes my queue struct.

```
int make_new_queue(struct queue* name)
{
    name = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    name->head = NULL;
    name->tail = NULL;
    name->element_counter = 0;
}
```

The problem I ran into is foolproofing this code. For example I initialised my first queue in my main function.

```
struct queue* first = make_new_queue(first);
```

But if somebody tries to do the same thing again somewhere in the middle of the code write:

```
first = make_new_queue(first);
```

it overrides it and makes the head and tail pointers NULL. The thing I can't figure out is how to make my make_new_queue function better and check if there is something in the queue that I provide it, but still let me initialise empty queues.

Sorry for my english. I hope you get the idea of what I want to do. Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't initialize the struct anyway, it initializes **a struct** but you don't return a pointer to it so it doesn't work, and trying to prevent that is not possible, just don't let any fool work with your code.

Comment: You can make a function that will allocate and return some NEW structure, without having some other structure to be passed there (why doing it anyway?).

Answer (score 1):

Initialize it to `NULL` and pass a pointer to pointer:

```
void make_new_queue(struct queue **name)
{
    if (*name != NULL) return; /* Yet initialized ? */
    *name = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    if (*name == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *name->head = NULL;
    *name->tail = NULL;
    *name->element_counter = 0;
}


struct queue *first = NULL;
make_new_queue(&first);
```

Comment: `if (*name != NULL) return;` or `if (*name == NULL) return;` ?

Comment: @SorryIwontTell `if (*name != NULL) return;` it seems that OP wants to exit If the pointer is already initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if you variable `name` is `NULL`.

If your variable is non-null, you can alloc and initialize your queue else just do what you want to do.

Comment: It won't work if it is containing some garbage (and it will contain it probabbly).

Comment: Both of you are right. I think is the behaviour of your function that is wrong. You must be create a function with no parameter which return a pointer to your initialized queue.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no good way to enforce what you want without discipline from the user. In my opinion, the best approach is to stick to known patterns.

You can use Alter Mann's approach to pass a pointer to a pointer to update the struct. The drawback is that is that you have to separate variable declaration and initialisation. It also relies on the user to initialise the pointer to the struct to `NULL`. If you forget it, the queue pointer will not be initialised and you don't even know, because you can't check against `NULL`.

```
struct stuff *stuff = NULL;

stuff_initialise(&stuff);
```

You can use your original approach to pass in the struct and return the same struct when it was initialised or a new one. It has the same problems as the first approach plus the possibility that you forget to assign the return value. You can, however, combine allocation and initialisation:

```
struct stuff *stuff = stuff_new(NULL);
```

The simplest way is not to pass the old pointer and rely on the user not to change the pointer after allocation. After all, the functions of the standard library suffer from the same problem:

```
char *buf = malloc(BUFSIZE);
buf = malloc(2 * BUFSIZE);             // Memory leak
buf++;                                 // Allowed, but a bad idea
free(buf);                             // Ouch!

FILE *f = fopen("palomino.txt", "r");
f = stdin;                             // Switch horses midstream?
```

You should design your API so that you have matching pairs of functions that define the scope of your struct:

```
struct stuff *stuff = stuff_create(...);

// use stuff ...
stuff_destroy(stuff);
```

Good naming should make clear that `stuff` acts as a handle and should not be changed and that after closing or destroying the handle, it is invalid. You should see these calls as first and last statements in functions. (This method is similar to the `malloc`/`free` or `fopen`/`fclose` pairngs of the standard library.)

Finally, if you as the user of a handle want to avoid accidential changes, you can define the pointer (not what it points to) as `const`:

```
struct stuff *const handle = stuff_create("X");

handle = stuff_create("Y");            // Compiler error
```

But I rarely see this. C programmers usually just use an unadorned pointer and remember to keep their fingers off the hotplate.